# Error while booting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, reset

I am a beginner with Ubuntu. My laptop is working fine and very fast ever since I made the transition from Windows! So no regrets...

In Windows I used Bluestacks to use Whatsapp on the PC. I also tried it for Ubuntu but didn't succeed. I don't need to install Whatsapp anymore. But right now every time I boot my System the is an error pop-up:

```
Error found when loading home/robert/.profile
/home/robert/.bashrc:line4:
home/robert/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:No such file or directory
```

What should I do to solve this problem. It's quit annoying and I don't think its getting betting on its own only worse.

Comment: Edit your question, and add line 4 from your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted your android sdk

To fix:

```
sudo su
```

To get root^

```
apt-get install nano -y --force-yes
cd /home/robert/
nano .profile
```

Remove (or put a hash before) line 4 (You can check the line count by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or go to a specific line with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)